# android-sdk has been officially discontinued upstream

Tags: android, macos, homebrew

When installing android sdk using home-brew I get this message

```
android-sdk has been officially discontinued upstream.
```

But I can't find an alternative package to use.  Is there a different one I should be using?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you don't want the full `android-studio` development app (Intellij IDE, etc) and just want the new command line tools...

Per the [discontinuation notice](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools)...

> This SDK Tools package is deprecated and no longer receiving updates. Instead, please use the new [command-line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio#cmdline-tools) package.

A quick search reveals that in homebrew land, this new "command-line tools" package is called `android-commandlinetools`.

```
$ brew remove android-sdk
$ brew install --cask android-commandlinetools
```

If you are looking for `adb` and such, these are ["SDK Platform Tools"](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line) and can be installed using `sdkmanager` (which was installed by the new `android-commandlinetools` package)...

```
$ sdkmanager --install platform-tools
```

Depending on where `sdkmanager` installs `platform-tools` you might need to update your `$PATH` or add symlinks in order to run `adb` and other platform-tools without an absolute path.

...or if you just want `adb`/etc you can skip the full commandlinetools and install `platform-tools` directly with homebrew. This has the side benefit of ensuring the newly installed `adb` is within your `$PATH` and is probably the best option for people that aren't doing android development and just want the latest `adb`, `fastboot`, etc.

```
$ brew install --cask android-platform-tools
```

Comment: I believe it's a cask so the command to install is `[$]> brew install --cask android-commandlinetools` and `[$]> brew install --cask android-platform-tools` https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/android-commandlinetools

Answer (score 0):

Per https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools

> Note: This SDK Tools package is deprecated and no longer receiving updates. Instead, please use the new command-line tools package.

check out https://developer.android.com/studio
`brew install android-studio`